# ¿Cómo corregir este fallo en Update y validación?

Tags: php, html5, base-de-datos, php5

Estoy elaborando un "Sistema de Asistencias", donde me muestre el "Motivo" si es Asistencia o Comida, fecha que ingresa, a si como también las entradas y salidas.

Estoy teniendo problema con las salidas de los usuarios, en vez de hacerme la actualización en la misma fila, me genera una nueva columna, para eso estoy implementando un Update, pero no funciona.

//Código corregido ya reparado

Este es mi el código

```
<?php

require_once 'conn.php';

$timezone = 'America/Tijuana';
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

if (isset($_POST['Matricula'])) {
    $Matricula = $_POST['Matricula'];
    $Motivo = $_POST['Motivo'];
    $date = date("d-m-Y");
    $time = date('H:i:s');
        
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM registro_expedientes WHERE Matricula = '$Matricula'";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows < 1) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Clave incorrecta - Favor de verificarla' . $Matricula;
    } else {
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $id = $row['Matricula'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM checador_registro WHERE Matricula='$id' AND Motivo='$Motivo' AND Fecha='$date' AND STATUS='0'";
        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $sql = "UPDATE checador_registro SET Salida='$time', STATUS='1' WHERE Matricula='$Matricula' AND Motivo='$Motivo' AND Fecha='$date'";
            $query = $conn->query($sql);
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO checador_registro(Matricula,Motivo,Entrada,Fecha,STATUS) VALUES('$Matricula','$Motivo','$time','$date','0')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            } else {
                $_SESSION['error'] = $conn->error;
            }
        }
    }
} 
$conn->close();
header("location: Checador.php");
```

Esta es la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos estás utilizando? ¿MariaDB, MySQL? Ponlo en las etiquetas, y quita _phpmyadmin_, ya que es meramente una herramienta de administración de base de datos.

Comment: Además, ¿a qué variable estás asignando el `UPDATE`?

Comment: @padaleiana Estaba asignado la variable $sql, pero al ejecutarla me arroja un error de Argumento ($Result).

 Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool. trate de resolverlo con un "mysql_multi_query"
pero tampoco quedo

Answer (score 1):

```
//aqui vamos a insertar datos
$insertar = "INSERT INTO checador_registro(Matricula,Motivo) VALUES
('$Matricula','$Motivo')";
```

Pues aqui, no estás insertando datos... estás declarando una variable, la cual contiene una consulta.

```
//Recorremos datos previamente registrados y los conectamos a una base de datos
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $insertar);
```

Y acá no estás recorriendo nada, ni conectando a nada. Estás haciendo que el insert into, que muestro antes, se ejecute, y se inserte una fila más a la base de datos, con los mismos valores que antes.

Lo peor de todo creo que viene acá.

```
//Creamos una variable para ser la consulta, "Traer nuestros datos "email y contraseña""
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as contar FROM registro_expedientes WHERE Matricula = '$Matricula'";
"UPDATE checador_registro SET Salida='$time', WHERE Matricula='$Matricula' AND Motivo='$Motivo'";
$query=$conn->query($sql);
```

Estás haciendo un select, si, donde cuentas la cantidad de filas que tienen esa matricula. Pero seguido... hay un update... el cual, no está asignado a nada... no se ejecuta, está perdido en el abismo.

Tampoco hay un `mysqli-query($conn, $update)` como para decir que quieres ejecutar la consulta.

No se de donde hayas sacado el codigo, o si lo has copiado, pero te recomiendo leerlo, y corregir que hace cada cosa, y cuando se ejecuta.

Comment: No, no lo he copiado, lo eh elaborado yo, pero como le he movido mucho, ahí eh ido  dejando las etiquetas. Gracias por ayudarme a leer el código, para comprenderlo de una mejor manera.

Comment: Trata de limpiar el codigo, para que no te enredes, debes tener claro que estas haciendo y que quieres hacer.

Comment: ok bro, voy a limpiarlo lo mas que se pueda en lo que va del día, mas tarde subo como quedo.

Comment: Hola bro, disculpa la tardanza me llevo mas de lo esperado, ahorita lo agrego.!